# Работа с @keydown в динамически добавленной textarea

Tags: html, vue.js

Делаю динамическую таблицу с textarea, у которой при keydown должна сработать функция toBold. Получается, у меня есть два инпута строк и столбцов, после заполнения их по клику срабатывает функция createTable. И здесь в textarea при клике опр.клавиш должна сработать функция, но никаких реакции. Снизу куски кода html, script

```
<table class="tasks_table" id="tablesDataIn">
   <tbody id="tablesBody"> </tbody>
</table>

createTable () {
  document.getElementById('tablesBody').innerHTML = ''
  const tableBody = document.getElementById('tablesBody')
  for (let i = 0; i < this.rowNumb; i++) {
   const tr = document.createElement('tr')
   for (let j = 0; j < this.colNumb; j++) {
     const td = document.createElement('td')
     td.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<textarea @keydown.ctrl.66="toBold"></textarea>')
     tr.append(td)
   }
   tableBody.append(tr)
  }
}

toBold () {
 console.log('clicked')
}
```

Comment: Vue об этом элементе ничего не знает. Вам нужно об этом как-то. Возможно, тут частично есть какой-то ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65229000

Comment: Но вообще Вам дали Vue не для того, чтобы Вы чисто через JS шаблон создавали) Вы же можете прямо в шаблоне эту же логику описать, циклы там есть, данные Вы всё равно знаете (или в data прописали, или с сервера получили). То есть это и так будет динамическая таблица

Comment: Спасибо Вам, точно надо так сделать